# Cannot receive API response

Tags: c#, python, curl

I am stuck on how to convert python code to c#.I tried many times but didnt receive API response.First i tried this
My python code

```
import sys
import base64
import requests
import json

file_path = 'limit.jpg'
image_uri = "data:image/jpg;base64," + base64.b64encode(open(file_path, "rb").read()).decode()
r = requests.post("https://api",
    data=json.dumps({'src': image_uri}),
    headers={"app_id": "YOUR_APP_ID", "app_key": "YOUR_APP_KEY",
             "Content-type": "application/json"})
print(json.dumps(json.loads(r.text), indent=4, sort_keys=True))
```

First attempt

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), "https://api."))
            {
                request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("app_id", id);
                request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("app_key",apiKey);

                request.Content = new StringContent("{ \"src\": \"data:image/jpeg;base64",PathToImage);
                request.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json");
                var response =  httpClient.SendAsync(request).Result;
                Console.WriteLine(    await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

            }
        }
```

But no luck API response here is 
**{"error":"SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input","error_info":{"id":"json_syntax","message":"SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input"}}**
I tried also to convert cURL -

```
curl -X POST https://api \
-H 'app_id: YOUR_APP_ID' \
-H 'app_key: YOUR_APP_KEY' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data '{ "src": "data:image/jpeg;base64,'$(base64 -i limit.jpg)'" }'
```

But no luck again.Maybe i am wrong with convertbase64 from image.

Comment: Concatenating strings and file contents like that will always cause problems, in Python, .NET *and* curl. The Python code *doesn't* concatenate strings though. It serializes a *dictionary*. The C# code should do the same - instead of constructing strings, serialize either a dictionary or an object and post that

Comment: BTW there's no `StringContent(string,string)` constructor. This code shouldn't even compile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Python code doesn't concatenate strings. What it does is :

1. Loads the contents of a file,
2. Encodes them with Base64
3. Create an image uri from the Base64 string
4. Create a *dictionary* whose key is `src` and value the image URI.
5. That dictionary is serialized as JSON.
6. The json string is posted to the API

The exact same steps in C# would be :

```
var data=File.ReadAllBytes(PathToImage);
var base64=Convert.ToBase64(data);
var imageUri="data:image/jpg;base64," + base64;
var json=JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new {src=imageUri});
var content=new StringContent(json,Encoding.UTF8,"application/json");

await _client.PostAsync(apiUrl,content);
```

The calls can be combined, but it's best to start with clean code before trying to shorten it. One difference with Python is that an anonymous object is created here with `new {src=imageUri}` instead of a dictionary

HttpClient instances are thread-safe and meant to be reused, not disposed. The API keys can be set once, when the HttpClient instance is created, eg :

```
_client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("app_id", id);
_client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("app_key",apiKey);
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you are passing PathToImage (which i believe has physical path to the image file) instead of base64 encoded image content. Please try below :

Edited Code :

```
request.Content = new StringContent("{ \"src\": \"data:image/jpeg;base64,",Convert.ToBase64(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(PathToImage)),"\" }");
```

Few syntatic corrections as below =>
Comma is missing after base64. (which i have added now)

At the end, you will have to specify "\" }" close the Open curly brackets with ending quotes to mark the end of json object